# Raspbmc Truecrypt mpount volume: Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper

Tags: linux, truecrypt, raspberry-pi, raspbmc

I am trying to mount a 3TB external Volume with Truecrypt on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbmc). I had the same Problem with raspbian running on the Raspberry Pi and dont know how to solve it. I found many other guys having trouble with this issue. Can someone give me some advise please?

```
pi@raspbmc:/dev$ truecrypt /dev/sda1 /media/extern1
Enter password for /dev/sda1:
Enter keyfile [none]:
Protect hidden volume (if any)? (y=Yes/n=No) [No]:
Error: /dev/mapper/control: open failed: No such device
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work:

```
sudo truecrypt -m=nokernelcrypto /dev/sda1 /media/extern1
```

?

Comment: What does this line of code do? How do I use it? How does it help solve the problem?